# SELECT Statement with if-else condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to modify sql statement which is very simple like

```
SELECT id
FROM page
WHERE name = "Test"
```

Now I want to change it something like

```
SELECT id
FROM page
WHERE name = "Test"
AND if idLanguage != idlanguage then idParent = idpage
```

what will the better way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT id
FROM page
WHERE name = "Test"
AND (idLanguage = idlanguage OR idParent = idpage)
```

is better because it is valid SQL syntax.

Comment: will this select all the records from the table every time?

Comment: @JoeGJoseph I assume that the OP meant different things by `idLanguage` and `idlanguage`. Perhaps it's a case sensitive database, or one of these will be replaced by a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a case statement? Please try:

```
SELECT id
FROM page
WHERE name = "Test" AND 
idParent = (CASE WHEN idLanguage <> idlanguage THEN idpage ELSE idParent END)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually wanting to set the value of idParent in the database then you need an `UPDATE` statement before your select.

```
UPDATE page SET idParent = idpage
WHERE name = "Test"
    AND idLanguage != idlanguage;

SELECT id FROM page
WHERE name = "Test"
```